# Como transformar lista de lista em matriz

Tags: python, numpy

Eu tenho um `csv` que contém 2 colunas uma com uma lista de 200 números (0.3,0.4,08...) e no outro um nome. Esse arquivo tem 50 linhas desse tipo. Gostaria de transformar essa lista de listas de números em um array que ficasse no fim com um tamanho de 50x200.

Tentei assim mas não deu certo :

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('exemplo.csv', sep=',')  
n=[]
p=[]
for row in dataset["nome"]:
    print (row) 
    p.append(row) 
for row in dataset["numeros"]:
    print (row) 
    n.append(row)
nome = np.array(p)
numeros = np.array(n)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado um Data Frame, como por exemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'listas':[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],'nomes':['nome 1','nome 2','nome 3']})

>>> df
   listas   nomes
0  [1, 2]  nome 1
1  [3, 4]  nome 2
2  [5, 6]  nome 3
```

Podemos pegar a coluna "listas" como um array da seguinte forma:

```
>>> df['listas'].apply(pd.Series).values
array([[1 2]
       [3 4]
       [5 6]], dtype=int64)
```

O que eu fiz foi quebrar a coluna com as listas em várias colunas, cada uma com um valor da lista, com o `.apply(pd.Series)` e depois pegar o valores com o `.values`.

Ou fazer direto: `df['listas'].tolist()` irá retornar uma matriz, então basta transformar em um array com `np.array(df['listas'].tolist())`.

Answer (score 1):

> **EDIT:** A versão anterior dessa resposta usava o método explode do pandas.
>   Também é uma solução possível, mas a solução abaixo, usando to_list, é
>   muito mais simples

Você pode colocar essas listas em um dataframe e usar o método to_list do pandas. Aqui um exemplo replicável:

```
import string
from random import choice

my_dict = {'lista_{}'.format(k): list(range(0,200)) for k in range(50)} #dicionário contendo 50 listas com números de 0 a 200

numeros = [my_dict['lista_{}'.format(m)] for m in range(50)] #variável numeros

alpha = string.ascii_lowercase

nomes = [choice(alpha)+choice(alpha)+choice(alpha)+choice(alpha) for m in range(50)] #variável nome (4 letras aleatórias)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Nomes': nomes, 'numeros': numeros}) #passando para um dataframe

new_columns = [choice(alpha)+choice(alpha)+choice(alpha) for j in range(200)] #criando uma lista com nomes das novas colunas que vamos criar (4 letras aleatórias)

df[new_columns] = pd.DataFrame(df.numeros.values.tolist()) #expandindo as listas

df
```

Output:

```
    Nomes   sij doz rwg ubn wbk bxp qzr wsz vmz ... iky crq sdh dbb oqq rnq tib rek ygj tao
0   ljmr    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   ... 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199
1   clay    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   ... 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199
2   rbue    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   ... 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199
3   zlsa    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   ... 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199
4   aetx    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   ... 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199
5   pgav    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   ... 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199
6   cxgb    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   ... 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199
7   wcpg    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   ... 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199
8   fadw    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   ... 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199
9   sqzo    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   ... 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199
10  hysc    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   ... 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199
11  fqnp    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   ... 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199
```

Confirmando o shape desejado:

```
df.iloc[:,1:].shape
```

Output:

```
50x200
```